# jQuery e.prevent default applies for children li too

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I am a beginner with jQuery. I created my own dropdown list, and the problem is when I create the `e.preventDefault();` for the dropdown it applies for the children too, and I would like to avoid that

html

```
<div id="wrapper" class="container">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">ABOUT PGP</a></li>
            <li class="parent"><a href="#">SERVICES</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="">Overview</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Industry Expertise</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Cross-Cultural Expertise</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Value Proposation</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="parent"><a href="">TRANSACTIONAL EXPERIENCE</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="">Select Transactions</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Prior Transactions</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="parent"><a href="#">TEAM</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Professionals</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Board of Directors</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Advisory Board</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="parent"><a href="">MEDIA</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="" class="long">PGP Press Releases & Announcements</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="long">PGP In The Newss</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">STRATEGIC PARTNERS</a></li>
            <li><a href="">CONTACT US</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('li.parent').bind('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $(this).children('ul.sub-menu').fadeIn(800);
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Could someone please give me a hint as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you not just use `$('li.parent > a')`? ie. target only the anchors contained within `parent`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `preventDefault` on parent only like this.

```
$('.parent').bind('click', function(e){
    if(event.target.className === 'parent')
        e.preventDefault();     
    $(this).children('ul.sub-menu').fadeIn(800);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$('li.parent, li.parent > a').bind('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('ul.sub-menu', this).fadeIn(800);
});
```

Try to get the direct child `>` and prevent the default action of the element.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the event.target / event.originalTarget to see what element generated the event and respond accordingly.

```
if (e.target.tagName === "LI" || e.target.tagName === "li")
{
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).children('ul.sub-menu').fadeIn(800);
}
```